# Convert Code from 2.7 to 3.5

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm very new to learning python, and was wondering if someone could convert a previously answered question so that it would work in Python 3.5. I would like to get the exact same info as the original question.

[Cannot get table data - HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024536/cannot-get-table-data-html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just give it a try

Comment: There's a [program](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) to do that for you, so no need to ask real people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the code and run this on the file, assuming it is called 'my_code.py'

```
2to3 -w my_code.py
```

The code will now be Python 3 code! This process will save the old Python 2 code as my_code.py.bak should you want to restore it.